# Catch cURL request from bash to PHP

Tags: php, bash, curl

I have few bash scripts which sends information from server to remote PHP script. I would like to add some sort of tokenization / authorization for these requests.

Here is example of bash script which sends JSON formatted information via cURL:

```
echo "${infoArr}" | curl -sS -A "$(hostname)" --request POST "${api_url}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d @-
```

And here is a receiving side written in PHP:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

...
```

My problem: I don't know how to receive authentication in PHP side when I send information with bash script.

I could add string to URL, like this https://d.tld/script.php?token=<...>. But this seems very primitive to me. Any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just send a token auth in a header like below,

```
    echo "${infoArr}" | curl -sS -A "$(hostname)" --request POST "${api_url}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer __YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE__"
-d @-
```

and in PHP you can read HTTP headers using function `getallheaders()`

for you

```
<?php
$headers = getallheaders();
/* 
* Place for authorization methods 
*/
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

...
```

just `var_dump($headers)` and see what you receive